# Creating a "Lagged" Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame and want to shift all but the first two columns down. Basically, I want to see a 'lagged' data frame. There seems to be a lot on how to get this for a single column (see [here](http://christophergandrud.blogspot.com/2013/05/slide-one-function-for-laglead.html)), but nothing to select most of the columns.

```
My data = 
d1 <- data.frame(month = c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "june"),
                conv =  c(1, 3, 6, 2, 3, 8),
                month = c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "june"),
                visit =  c( 1,  2,  4,  8, 16, 32),
                click =  c(64, 62, 36,  5,  6,  3))
d1

Desired output = 
d2 <- data.frame(month = c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "june"),
                conv =  c(1, 3, 6, 2, 3, 8),
                month = c(NA, "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may"),
                visit =  c( NA, 1,  2,  4,  8, 16),
                click =  c(NA, 64, 62, 36,  5,  6))
d2
```

Help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cheap method:

```
cbind(d1[,1:2],head(rbind(NA,d1),-1)[,-(1:2)])
```

Result:

```
  month conv month.1 visit click
1   jan    1    <NA>    NA    NA
2   feb    3     jan     1    64
3   mar    6     feb     2    62
4   apr    2     mar     4    36
5   may    3     apr     8     5
6  june    8     may    16     6
```